# Rails query based on results count of has_many model column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

```
Customer has_many Shifts through Jobs
Shifts belong_to Truck
Trucks belong_to Fleet
```

I'm trying to gauge the top 5 most used `fleets` that a customer has booked shifts with, as well as the number of shifts. Ideally, I would get `Fleet A: X shifts` and so on.

I tried using `customer.shifts.joins(:fleets).select('*, count(shifts.fleet_id) as fleet_count').order('fleet_count desc')` but I don't really know where to go other than manually looping through all of a customer's shifts in order to find the most utilized fleets.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: w/o diving too deeply into this problem (sorry eating lunch) because this basically sounds like it needs to be up-to-date when you need it and not via some recursive method call. You may want this logic to reside in your database and update a column via a trigger when shifts are updated. However database level logic introduces other maintenance/upgrade issues so... YMMV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, working through this with my colleagues, we seemed to have found the answer.

`Customer.find(8).shifts.joins(:fleet).group('fleets.id').select('fleets.name as fleet_name, count(*) as shift_count').order('shift_count desc').limit(5).collect{|f|[f.fleet_name, f.shift_count]}`

Grouping the `Shifts` into the `Fleets` by `fleets.id` structured the rest of the query better and allowed me to collect the data into a meaningful hash.

Answer (score 2):

So, this is answer focuses on the SQL, I'm not sure the best way to translate that back to active record methods. It's a query that is focused on the Shifts table, and not really concerned with the Customer table, you don't even really need to join in the Customer table. Join Shifts, Trucks, and Fleets. Filter the results with a `where` clause on `shifts.customer_id` that matches the customer you're interested in. Select `count(*)` and use `group by fleet.id`.  Order by the count and limit the results to 5, and you'll have your result set.

```
select count(*) as shift_count, fleets.id from shifts
  inner join trucks on shifts.truck_id = trucks.id
  inner join fleets on trucks.fleet_id = fleets.id
  where shifts.customer_id = 1
  group by fleets.id
  order by shift_count DESC
  limit 5;
```

To translate this back into active record code, I think the main thing you can do is find a way to include the `group by` clause into what you already have in the Customers class.